# Why is st_write not saving this dataframe as a shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, r, sf

I have been working with sf package for several weeks now. I have been able to figure out the solution of problems by myself or searching on forums. However, this one has been demanding too much time and I don't know what is the problem yet.

The task is quite basic, I want to write a dataframe as .shp with the following code, which is pretty straightforward:

```
st_write(UPS, "Shapefiles/UPS.shp", layer_options = "GEOMETRY=AS_XY", delete_layer = TRUE)
```

Some of the variables are the following (only SHAPE_Leng, SHAPE_Area and geometry are geographical).[image: enter code here]

And these are the descriptions of the variables (I cannot generate a random database to replicate since this specific dataframe has been quite a trouble):

[image]

When I execute the aforementioned code I get the following output:

```
Deleting layer `UPZ2' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Writing layer `UPZ2' to data source `Shapefiles/UPZ2.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
options:        GEOMETRY=AS_XY 
Updating existing layer UPZ2
Writing 111 features with 11 fields and geometry type Multi Polygon.
Unknown field name `UPlCd': updating a layer with improper field name(s)?
Error in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  : 
  Write error
In addition: Warning message:
In abbreviate_shapefile_names(obj) :
  Field names abbreviated for ESRI Shapefile driver
```

So, as you can see, I don't have any variable named UPlCd, so I don't have figured out yet how to proceed. In addition, I don't know what is `Error in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  :`  is referring to since no variable is named like that.

The question is: how can I succesfully write this dataframe as a .shp file? (and in the process, which details I'm missing).

I have seen these responses ([1](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/456), [2](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/53) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60454067/cpl-write-ogr-error-when-writing-out-shape-file-in-r)) but they have not been helpful to clarify which problem I'm having with this dataframe so I cannot save it.

Comment: `UPlCd` is the shortened name for your "UPlCodigo" field which is too long for shapefiles. This should only generate a warning and not an error though. Test if it is a problem with field names by renaming all columns to something simple and short and trying again.

Comment: When exporting to shapefile more things can go wrong than if you export to other file types. Your file can be too big, it can have unsupported field types, relations and attribute names or even too many attributes. If you don't specifically need a shapefile I would reccommend you too export as geopackage, with `"Shapefiles/UPS.gpkg"`. Here's a website pointing out shortcomings of shapefiles you should be aware of: http://switchfromshapefile.org/